# Count lines with awk, regardless of line ending style

Tags: awk

What's the best way to count the number of line in a file with awk, regardless of line-ending style (DOS/Windows, UNIX, etc.)?

Comment: GNU Awk allows regular expressions as record separators. So you could do `gawk 'END { print NR }' RS='\n\r|\n|\r\n'`. But that's an extension.

Comment: That actually *still* reports only one line for the file I'm trying it on. When I open the file in question in TextMate, it is properly line-numbered, so I'm assuming it's not corrupt.

Comment: But, excuse me if this is obvious to you, the example by litb did not include CR *only* line endings, but that seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Blast! I can't believe that didn't occur to me. Now I feel dumb. @litb -- if you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a dos2unix or unix2dos on the file first, before using awk.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script for counting the number of lines, and get the perfect result. The script for the same is available here, [Count No. of lines in UNIX which have data](http://www.code2learn.com/2012/09/count-number-of-lines-in-file-in-unix.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
grep -c '^.*$' filename
```

Comment: Nope -- same thing. It reports one line for files using the CR-only line ending style.